# Is it possible to extend Cisco's MIB tree?

Tags: cisco, monitoring, snmp

One of the most notable feature of [NetSnmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) is the possibility to extend an OID tree running aribtrary commands using the extend and the pass persist [methods](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tut%3aExtending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts).

I was wondering if there is such a fuature also in Cisco devices.

For example is possible to answer with the hitcout of an ACL? Is so, how to choose the OID? To my knowledge there is not a private branch for custom OIDs.

Comment: If you use '| ?' after the show command you want to parse output from, you will see the options for |, which will then let you include, exclude, grep/egrep and other options depending on platform and software version.

Comment: Thank you @cpt_fink but actually I'm asking a way to issue a "show command" after a snmp get to a specific (custom) OID. It it's not clear let me know.

Comment: Are you saying you want to trigger a show command from an SNMP GET?  Please give an example of what exactly you want from the router or switch; it would help to have concrete information

Comment: @MikePennington I've edited the question giving some more detail. Actually I was thinking at a more general use case.

Comment: Late reply... I would suggest something using SSH and expect instead of SNMP for this use case.